# Stepping through an array of pointers to strings - "lvalue required as increment operand"

Tags: c, arrays, lvalue

I'm confused about this program which I'm going to state here. 
I wrote two simple programs to print a list of strings. First I made an array of pointers to the strings. And this is how I tried to do it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    char *a[] = {"Hello", "World"};

    while (--i >= 0) {
        printf("%s\n", *a++); // error is here.
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I need it to print

```
Hello
World
```

but there is compilation error and it says,

```
lvalue required as increment operand.
```

Then I changed the program to the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printout(char *a[], int n)
{
    while (n-- > 0)
        printf("%s\n", *a++);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    char *a[] = {"Hello", "World"};

    printout(a,i);
    return 0;

}
```

Then it worked as expected.

My question is, What's the difference happen when I pass the array name to a function? Why didn't it work the first time (I suspect that "array names cannot be modified" is the reason But WHY in the second program, it allowed me to increment)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
*a++
```

`++` requires its operand to be a modifiable lvalue.

In the first example, `a` is an array. In the second example, when passed to a function as argument, the array decays to a pointer (to its first element), so the code compiles.

Comment: There are two rules at play here. First, an expression of array type is, in most but not all contexts, implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's initial element; that's what happens to `a` in the call `printout(a,i)`. Second, a function parameter of array type is *adjusted* to be of pointer type, so the parameter declaration `char *a[]` really means `char **a`. The `a` in `main` is an array object. The parameter `a` in `printout()` is a pointer object.